# Autofac Register Concrete Class

Tags: c#, autofac, hangfire, autofac-configuration, hangfire-autofac

I am getting the below error on registering a concrete class using Autofac

This is the class

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
public class NoRetryJob<T> where T : IRecurringJob
{
    private T Job { get; set; }
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public NoRetryJob(T job)
    {
        Job = job;
        Job.Error += LogError;
        Job.Info += LogInfo;
    }
}
```

This is how I am doing the registration with autofac

```
 builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NoRetryJob<>)).InstancePerDependency();

 builder.RegisterType<CachingService>().As<ICachingService>();
```

Calling the above class as

```
JobRegistration.Add<NoRetryJob<PageCachingJob>>(nameof(PageCachingJob), j => j.Run(), Cron.Daily(1));
```

PageCachingJob class -

```
 public class PageCachingJob : BaseJob, IRecurringJob
{
    private readonly ICachingService _cachingService;
    public DateTime? LastSuccessfulExecutionOn { get; set; }

    public PageCachingJob(ICachingService cachingService) : base()
    {
        _cachingService = cachingService;
    }

    protected override void RunJob()
    {
        _cachingService.ClearRedisCache();
    }
}


 public class JobRegistration
{
    public static void Add<T>(string jobName, Expression<Action<T>> methodCall, string cron)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobName, methodCall, cron, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
    }
}
```

BaseJob Class

```
 public abstract class BaseJob
{
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public event EventHandler<string> Info;
    public event EventHandler<string> Error;

    protected BaseJob()
    {

    }

    protected abstract void RunJob();

    public virtual JobResponse Run()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        var response = new JobResponse();
        try
        {
            logger.Info($"Job {this.GetType().Name} - started.");
            stopwatch.Start();

            RunJob();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            logger.Info($"Job {this.GetType().Name} - successful.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.LogMessages.Add("Exception" + ex.Message);
            response.LogMessages.Add("Stacktrace : " + ex.StackTrace);
            logger.Error($"Job {this.GetType().Name} - failure." + ex);
            LogError(response.LogMessages, $"Job {this.GetType().Name} - failure.", ex);
        }

        logger.Info($"Job {this.GetType().Name} - duration: {stopwatch.Elapsed:g}.");
        return response;
    }

    private void LogError(IList<string> messages, string message, Exception ex)
    {
        messages.Add(DateTime.Now + ": ERROR " + message);
        Error?.Invoke(this, message + " " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Interface -

```
 public interface IRecurringJob
{
    event EventHandler<string> Info;
    event EventHandler<string> Error;

    DateTime? LastSuccessfulExecutionOn { get; set; }

    JobResponse Run();
}
```

ICachingService interface

```
 public interface ICachingService
{
    bool ClearRedisCache();
}
```

CachingService class

```
 public class CachingService : ICachingService
{
    public CachingService()
    {
    }

    public bool ClearRedisCache()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Getting the below exception

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'PacDig.Atlantic.Schedule.Jobs.NoRetryJob`1[PacDig.Atlantic.Schedule.Jobs.PageCachingJob]'
>   can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot
>   resolve parameter 'PacDig.Atlantic.Schedule.Jobs.PageCachingJob job'
>   of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(PacDig.Atlantic.Schedule.Jobs.PageCachingJob)'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure you've posted enough code to determine a fix for your issue.  What is JobRegistration?

Comment: Also I don't see a registration for PageCachingJob... are you missing builder.RegisterType<PageCachingJob>().AsSelf() ?

Comment: @Mick I have added a jobRegistration class

Comment: @Hardsheet its still not https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hardsheet you'll need to create a wholly self contained minimal example that replicates your issue.  If people can't compile and execute the code they can't verify the fix for the issue.  The best you'll get are guesses at a fix

Comment: @Mick I have added all the relevant classes

Comment: Hey @Mick I tried adding

builder.RegisterType<PageCachingJob>().AsSelf()

And it is working now. 

Thanks heaps. you saved my day

Comment: When dealing with Autofac, it is key to read the exact message. `Cannot resolve parameter 'PacDig.Atlantic.Schedule.Jobs.PageCachingJob job' of constructor 'Void .ctor(PacDig.Atlantic.Schedule.Jobs.PageCachingJob)'.` shows very clearly that `PageCachingJob` is the issue. 99% of the time, that is because you forgot to register that specific thing.

Comment: @Mick  Do you know how to add a delay of 1 min in a recurring job which is running after every 5 mins

Comment: @Harsheet That is a new question.

Comment: @mjwills I have added a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340010/delay-interval-in-recurring-jobs-in-hangfire

And one more as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339426/stop-recurring-jobs-hangfire-before-deployment-to-production-environment