# Stop recurring jobs (Hangfire) before deployment to production environment

Tags: c#, hangfire

Is there a way to stop the recurring jobs to run immediately when the server restart or right after the deployment is done?

And If we delete the recurring job from the dashboard, how to add it again?

Thanks

Comment: A recurring job shouldnt fire when the server starts; could you add the code you use to add the jobs? The CRON parameter should set when the job starts. As for your second question, afaik you cant, at least not from the dashboard. You can offcourse do it in code in the same manner you added the jobs in the first place.