# Delay interval in recurring jobs in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

We have a recurring job in Hangfire that runs every 5 minutes.

But we want to wait for 1 min after every 5 min when the next job will start.

Is there any way to do this in hangfire.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by wait 1 minute?

Comment: @mjwills Before starting the next job, we want to add a delay of 1 minute..When one job runs - add a delay of 1 min - run the next job - and so on

Comment: Why not just run it every 6 minutes rather than every 5?

Comment: The job is to clear the output cache. We want to wait for a minute before starting the next job, so that in that last minute, if someone updates something and we need to clear that as well. So in that last minute (delay) we will get any other cache to clear and then run the job

Comment: Why not just set the `OutputCache` to expire after 5 minutes? Why do you need a Hangfire job?